# Hover CSS with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to edit the rendering of an element when hovering. To achieve this, I created a `button` and I want the first `click` to set the hover rendering and the second `click` to reset the hover rendering. Currently, the `hover` style appears even when I'm not on the `div`:

```
$("#editer-script").click(function() {
  var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');

  if (clicks) {
    $('.contenu-editable').mouseover(function(){
        $('.contenu-editable').css("background-color", "transparent");
        $('.contenu-editable .fa.fa-pencil').css("display", "none");
    });
    $("#editer-script").text('Rendre éditable');
  } else {
    $('.contenu-editable').mouseover(function(){
        $('.contenu-editable').css("background-color", "#f4f6f9");
        $('.contenu-editable .fa.fa-pencil').css("display", "inline-block");
    });
    $("#editer-script").text('Ne pas rendre éditable');
  }

  $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
});
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: question is not clear

Comment: use `mouseenter`

Comment: @KiranShahi, I edited my question for clarity.

Comment: Please provide html too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use two different css classes. One default and one for the change of the `hover` effects. And then just `toggle` the second class on `click` of the button element.

It's mutch easier than try to do it your way and it could be easily changed and extended just in css. No need to touch the script in the future.

```js
$("#editer-script").click(function() {
  var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');

  $('.contenu-editable').toggleClass('special', !clicks);
  $("#editer-script").text(clicks ? 'Rendre éditable' : 'Ne pas rendre éditable');

  $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
});
```

```css
.contenu-editable:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.contenu-editable:hover .fa.fa-pencil {
  display: none;
}

.contenu-editable.special:hover {
  background-color: #f4f6f9;
}

.contenu-editable.special:hover .fa.fa-pencil {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="editer-script">Rendre éditable</button>
<div class="contenu-editable">
  <i class="fa fa-pencil">pencil</i>
  content
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but it seems that classes are not added when I click on the #edit-script div. The text changes correctly...

Comment: How can I add the "sortable" feature in the same way as the "special" class ?

Comment: That is a bit mutch for this question and would be off-topic here. Please create a new question with the changes you did, and tell us whats the problem and what you want to do. We will help you then within the new question. ;) @Pierre-ClémentCazon